# How to make curve to mesh geometry node's "fill cap" option to respect holes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When using fill curve on a joined curve, it produces a shape with holes : [image: Screenshot with fill curve]

However, with curve to mesh, this hole is not appearing :

[image: Screenshot with curve to mesh]

How to conserve these holes with Curve to mesh ?

Comment: Of course "the holes" are not appearing with _Curve to Mesh_. When you use _Fill Curve_, multiple vertices of the curve get connected to create polygons to fill space between them. But _Curve to Mesh_ is used to take the curve as a path on which to extrude along the profile curve. If you want the curve to be filled and give a height to it, you have to first use _Fill Curve_ and then _Extrude Mesh_. But for this you need at least Blender 3.1, the _Extrude Mesh_ isn't implemented in 3.0 yet (or maybe 3.0.1? I still use 3.0.0).

Comment: In the mean time, I have found a solution using *curve to points* to provide the cap location, then *instance to points* to put the result of  *fill curve*

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

You could use a trick where you simply apply the node `Mesh Boolean` to two independent meshes that you created with `Curve to Mesh`.

[image]

Or you create your mesh first with the node `Curve to Mesh`, but without *Caps*, and add the caps manually using `Instance on Points` at the beginning and end of the curve.

[image]